# Display posts from multiple user roles

Tags: loop, user-roles

I have created a custom loop to show only admin posts, but now I would like it to display posts from both admins and contributors.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
echo "<div class='post_wrap " . $infinite . "'>";
$users_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
                                        'role' =>  'administrator',

                                        'orderby' => 'display_name'
                                        ) );
$site_admins = array();
$results = $users_query->get_results();
foreach($results as $user) {
    $site_admins[] = $user->ID;
}

$admins = implode(',',$site_admins);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'author' => $admins, 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 10));
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Query user data on admins
$administrators = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' =>  'administrator' ) );

// Query user data on contributors
$contributors = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' =>  'contributor' ) );

// Save admin IDs
foreach( $administrators->results as $u )
    $user_ids[] = $u->ID;

// Save contributor IDs
foreach( $contributors->results as $u )
    $user_ids[] = $u->ID;

// Little cleanup
unset( $u, $administrators, $contributors );

// Save paged value (for paginating results)
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 

// query_posts()
query_posts(
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'author__in' => $user_ids,
        'paged' => $paged
    )
);

// If the query has data
if( have_posts() ) :

    // Post loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : 

        // Setup post data
        the_post();
        ?>

        <!-- Do HTML markup and template tags here, eg. the_content(), the_title() etc.. -->
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php
    endwhile;

// End "If the query has data"
endif;
```

@1fixdotio : `WP_User_Query` returns an object of each user. `WP_Query` takes user ids only so we have to extract the ids from the user objects. I think that is the only mistake there.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS! Thank you so much. This worked perfectly :D

Comment: Cleaned the code up for you somewhat, should hopefully make for easier reading. Note, `query_posts` should be fine for use inside a page template or selective uses where the main query won't be used otherwise, else `WP_Query` would be more appropriate.